Is there a way to reduce hair guide strands with geometry nodes?
Attached is an example of hair without children strands. As you can see there is a high density of strands even without having children hairs.  Is there a way to thin out the guide strands, i.e., reduce the density of the hairs using geometry nodes?
I realise I can do this with the Brush tools to thin out the density, but I want to know if there is a systematic method to do this with Geometry nodes, as I will need to perform the same process on many hairs while maintaining their vertex order.


you can delete randomly a certain percentage of the hair curves with a Delete Geometry node and a Random Value (Boolean) node. It's shown here: https://youtu.be/6_USH9c_vNU?feature=shared&t=1349, Delete Hair GN node group at 22:41 -- However, I am not sure whether it meets your "maintaining their vertex order" requirement.
